# change input source language programmatically OSx

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm having problem to change a **textfield** input language source through codes !
All I want is to **change** the **keyboard language** to specific language when ever I **enter** a **textfield**.

I'm already searched here and just found some small guidance for Iphone but I'm working on **OSx App**.

Thank you guys helping me again !

**EDIT:**
well ! new approaches :
If I change my **system preferences** to appropriate language then most of the problems solved !
Date formatter become true and if I use this code snippet I can achieve correct language name ( before I just got **en**):

```
NSLocale * locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];        
NSString * localLanguage = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode] ;
NSLog (@"Language : %@", localLanguage);
```

BUT, I want to change the **keyboard input language** without changing the whole system preference. In fact, I want to change the **Text Input service language** to other **installed** language ( I have 2 ) when I enter into a special **textfield** ! ( is it clear ? )

Comment: I was looking for this for an iPhone app. Could you point me to the element you found? I will try to return the favor. Also, I was told that it's worth adding a report to Apple's Bug Reporter - radr. David

Comment: @David DellMonte, Sorry my friend for my late answer, you can find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150576/change-ios-apps-language-on-the-fly).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I answered my own question AGAIN !

for whom that may visit this question :
 to get reached the user's **keyboard language Input sources** you have to follow this instructions :

1. **TIS** ( Text Input Service ) is related to **Carbon framework**. So, first of all you have to import **carbon.h** to your implementation file:

   `#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>`
2. **Add** carbon framework to your framework resource. To do this you have to navigate to **Mac OSx Application Target -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries -> add** carbon frame work.
3. to change the keyboard input source, you can use for example `controlTextDidBeginEditing` delegate to detect user's `textfield` selection.Then you can select the proper language from installed language sources. for example I have two language installed, **en** and **fa** so I have 2 keyboard layout in language bar. Then you can select the language by selecting it's index.
4. to find your desired language index you can use this :
   `NSArray *langs=[NSLocale preferredLanguages];`
   **langs** included by languages that you can reached by it's indexes.
5. Now, it's time to change text input source programmatically using this codes :
   `NSArray*langsArray=(NSArray*)TISCreateInputSourceList(NULL,FALSE); //make a list of installed languages

   TISInputSourceRef faSource=(TISInputSourceRef)[langsArray objectAtIndex:1]; //my second language is farsi (persian)

   TISSelectInputSource(faSource); // now second language selected for keyboard input resource`

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I have the same problem in iPhone app, and I can't find Carbon FrameWork ?

Comment: @Prooshani Ten years later and your answer is still very helpful! Many thanks!