# iOS - Reload view from NIB file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change iOS app's language on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150576/change-ios-apps-language-on-the-fly)

Hello everyone,

In order to be able to change the language of my app on the fly I need to be able to reload the currently displayed view from the appropriate nib file. How can I do that?