# Change app language programmatically

Tags: ios, internationalization

I'm developing an iOs application with latest SDK and XCode 4.2.

I need to add a menu where user can changes only app language (I **don't want** to change device language).

I also want to use `NSLocalizedString`.

How can I do this?

Comment: A very similar question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150576/change-ios-apps-language-on-the-fly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130853/how-to-force-an-app-to-change-language-in-ios-objective-c/34131794#34131794

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
// switching to polish locale
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[@"pl"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: The important thing is, that these statements are executed before the app is launched: do it in main.m in the main() function, before UIApplicationMain() is called.

Comment: If this needs to be done in the main(), then how is this going to help with a menu where the user can change the interface language of the app..?