# Assign specific language in multi-language ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, multilingual

I have a multi-language ios app, it can switch to correct language depends on ios system location. I want to know, for example, the system language is english, how do I assign app language to German or other languages?

Comment: The same way that iOS does it (taking it from the appropriate file), except you need to do it manually since the system will not do it for you.

Comment: Check my answer, there is an example http://stackoverflow.com/a/14742213/1702413

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this in main.m in the main() function, before UIApplicationMain() is called, the important thing is that these statements are executed before the app is launched

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"es", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"]; //switching to spanish locale
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your default language in your `Info.plist` file. The setting is called `Localization native development region`. This language will be used as a default one.