# Forcing NSLocalizedString to change Language - not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nslocalizedstring, nslocale

I want to Refer : 
[Change iOS app's language on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150576/change-ios-apps-language-on-the-fly) first, in which a way to change Language is Given, i used it, it is working, but it requires Two ReLaunch of Application to take changes over Application. 
I want to do something in which, just on Button click my language should change

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"de", nil] 
                                          forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this -> `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

**Edited Post**

Put this macro in the Prefix.pch:

```
#define currentLanguageBundle [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] ofType:@"lproj"]]
```

and where ever you need a localized string use:

```
NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"GalleryTitleKey", nil, currentLanguageBundle, @"")
```

For Setting use this as you are already using:-

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"de", nil] 
                                          forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Comment: I am Doing this Also. but even though the Reflection is Observed after two Launches