# change keyboard language Input sources programmatically in SANDBOX (TISSelectInputSource)

Tags: macos, sandbox, macos-carbon, appstore-sandbox

I am trying to change keyboards layout programmatically. I found solution here [change input source language programmatically OSx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074757/change-input-source-language-programmatically-osx), but it is not working in sandboxed application. I found out I need to set an exception in entitlements file, more precisely com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-lookup.global-name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
      <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
      <true/>
      <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-lookup.global-name</key>
      <array>
        <string>com.apple.tsm.portname</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

When I run an application I still get an error `16.03.15 17:47:48,000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: my_app(3704) deny mach-lookup com.apple.tsm.portname` in console. Here is documentation for changing keyboard layout, but nothing about sandbox. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Reference/TextInputSourcesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/TISSelectInputSource
Any ideas?